# Login to SQL Server Single User Mode when NT AUTHORITY Disabled

Tags: sql-server, passwords, single-user

I will connect to SQL Server with single user mode  `-m; parameter`

My SQL Server is SQL Server 2008 R2

but when NT AUTHORITY Disabled can not login even local admin user

I don't want to reset the `sa` password just I will login into SQL and create a new user.

I have admin local password some application use `sa` to connect to SQL and hard code `sa` password on app.

I don't want  to reset `sa` password.

Now when start SQL service on single user mode with -m parameter when connect with sqlcmd or sql management I get error the account is disabled.

Comment: Which dbms? (The SQL language itself has no such parameters.)

Comment: sql server 2008 r2

Comment: Please post the actual error message (in text format). Also, are you sure the only available session is not getting occupied by the "sa" user (even if this should return a different error)?

Comment: @GiovanniLuisotto Yes I sure only sa connect to serve on single mode . i also run /m sqlcmd  to run only one session